# Solution within solutions vs 2010

Tags: c#

Wondering if its' possible to have solution within solution in vs 2010?
How? 
thanks alot

Comment: What's a solution within a solution? You can have multiple projects in a single solution. Is that not enough?

Comment: What are you asking for?

Comment: Why would you need that? As Joel points out, you can simply have multiple projects insisde a solution. Isn't that enough?

Comment: We have nearly 200 projects and there were discussions how to best do that and it came up and was wondering if was possible

Comment: This is not answer for you but maybe you can give it a try: Solution Load Manager http://bit.ly/9nb83B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Visual Studio doesn't support solutions in solutions (I feel this is a feature that should be supported) the closest approximation you can have is create groupings of your projects with multiple solutions so you have like

- Client.sln
- Server.sln
- Master.sln that has all of the projects

This adds some additional effort when solution level changes are made such as adding/removing projects but I've used this methodology previously with good success.

In most instances work will never need to be done in the Master.sln except for integration work and potentially deployments depending how your setup for them. So instead of having a solution with 200 projects that is massively slow to open/build you'll have much smaller working subsets.

It's really unfortunate that VS doesn't support this natively so that the master solution is automatically maintained by actions of the subsolutions.

Comment: I think the above idea implies the following structure in VCS:
/src/Master.sln 
/src/Server.sln 
/src/Client.sln 
/src/project-01/prj-01.csproj
/src/project-02/prj-02.csproj

Answer (score 6):

No.

However, you can organize projects into Solution Folders.

Comment: Article about that: right-click solution in solution explorer -> add -> new solution folder. Nice article, isn't it...?

Answer (score 3):

**No**

However you can have Solution folders to organize your projects inside of.
Organizing your projects into folders is nice because you can right click on a folder and build the projects inside that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid no, but you can have multiple projects in a solution. I see no point in doing that as the solution has mostly just organizational purpose...

Comment: thanks for your reply.we have nearly 200 projects and we were discussing how best split them into solutions and organize them and it came up "solution within solution"